# debugging bash 4.3.2 (npm installs not working)

Tags: bash, npm

I just downloaded bash version 4.3.2 I wanted to play around with it a bit, but am realizing that when I do an npm install (typescript, gulp) and check the version of the install I keep getting back

```
-bash: typescript: command not found
-bash: gulp: command not found
```

Here is my version

```
   GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

Although

```
 $BASH_VERSION returns the original version
```

I do have node and npm installed.

I am stuck right now on any form of development on my mac at this point.  Any insight to fixing this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to the bash version, you just need to add the typescript executable to your `PATH` environment variable:

`PATH=$PATH:<executable-dir>`

e.g. `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/npm/bin`

Comment: Yeah, but the gulp problem is what is also killing me.  I am wondering if removing this update from homebrew is possible

Comment: Likewise for gulp, add it to your `PATH`.

Comment: In node modules I have gulp npm and typescript.  I did brew uninstall bash and gulp worked.  However typescript still isnt

Comment: `bash` 4 is *not* your problem. The problem is with your `PATH`. Fix that, and `typescript` and `gulp` will work again.